# Capture the output of command line in a variable in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to capture the output of the command below in a variable.

Command:

```
find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT
```

The output is :

```
./FILE1.TXT
```

I want to capture './FILE1.TXT' into 'A' variable. But when I am trying

```
A=`find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT`
```

then this command is displaying the data of the file. But I want `./FILE1.TXT` value in the variable A.

Comment: Please improve the formulation of your question. A file name is not the same as a file content (and some files have no or several names since files are [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode))

Comment: It isn't obvious why the command in back-ticks is copying the data in your file into your variable rather than the name of the file. It is generally better to use the `$(...)` notation for [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), but shouldn't affect things. You could use `-print` as part of the `find` command, but it shouldn't matter. It might be that you're mishandling the code that reports the file name; it should be just `echo "$A"` or `printf "%s\n" $A` or something similar. Be wary of spaces (or, worse, newlines) in file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ls *.txt
test1.txt  test.txt
# find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt"
./test1.txt
./test.txt
# A=$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt")
# echo $A
./test1.txt ./test.txt
```

You can ignore `-maxdepth 1` if you want to. I had to use it for this example.

Or with a single file:

```
# ls *.txt
test.txt
# find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt"
./test.txt
# A=$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt")
# echo $A
./test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you try ?

```
A="`find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT`"
```

and

```
A="`find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT -print`"
```

Answer (score 0):

A file does not have any value, but does have a content. Use the following to display that content.

```
  find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT -exec cat {} \;
```

If you want all the contents (of all such files) in a variable, then

```
  A=$(find . -iname 'FIL*'.TXT -exec cat {} \;)
```

BTW you could have used

```
  find . -iname 'FIL*.TXT' -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

If you want the names of such files in a variable, try

```
  A=$(find . -iname 'FILE*.txt' -print)
```

BTW, on *some* several recent interactive shells (`zsh`, `bash` [version 4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) but not earlier versions) just write

```
  A=**/FILE*.txt
```

My feeling is that the `**` feature is by itself worth switching to a newer shell, but it is just my opinion.

Also, don't forget that files may have several or no names. Read about [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) ...

Comment: But I want the file name because file name is dynamic. It can be different after FIL word.

Comment: The above commands are displying the file content. I don't want to see the file content. Could you please suggest different solution.

Comment: hey, the last one is not working. cat: **/FILE*.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: The double star `**/` is an extension in *some* shells, like `zsh` or `bash` version 4 but not version 3. You could consider using `zsh`